# this.findOne is not a function (mongoose imported)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am trying to make a mongoose static like this

```
UserShema.statics.login = async function(username,password){
    const user = await this.findOne({username:username});

    if (user) {
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (auth) {
          return user;
        }
        throw Error('incorrect password');
      }
      throw Error('incorrect email');
}
```

imports:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
```

I looked online and it bascally told my no arrow function and import mongoose which i did i just wanted the findone function to work. It will find the user then return the user.

Comment: your english explanation is very hard to understand

Comment: include mongoose connection code also

Comment: I'm pretty sure static methods shouldn't use `this`